# gnuplot all points y value undefined log

Tags: logging, gnuplot

I would like to plot the log of my first and second column of my file "hmax.txt".
But I get this error message and I don't understand why ?
I haven't any 0 in my second column.

```
plot 'hmax.txt' u (log($1)):(log($2))
                                     ^
"plot", line 18: all points y value undefined!
```

my plot file :

```
set term png size 800,800
set output "lois.png"
set style line 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 0.5
set title 'hmax en fonction de t' font ",20"
set xlabel 'temps t'
set ylabel 'hmax'
plot 'hmax.txt' u 1:2 with lp ls 1

unset key
set term png size 800,800
set output 'loiss.png'
set style line 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 0.5
set title 'log(hmax) en fonction de log(t)' font ",20"
set xlabel 'log(t)'
set ylabel 'log(hmax)'
set logscale xy
plot 'hmax.txt' u (log($1)):(log($2)) with lp ls 1
```

And here my data file "hmax.txt" 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ciutnt32knBRhBIjCcR6aaFfa8NxBRuM/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values in column2 are ranging from `0.316` to `1`. And `log(1)=0` and `log(0.316)=-1.15`.
So all your y-values in `plot 'hmax.txt' u (log($1)):(log($2)) with lp ls 1` are zero or negative.

How do you want to plot negative values in a logarithmic plot where you set both, x-axis and y-axis to logarithmic scale?

Depending what you want to do, maybe:

```
set logscale xy
plot 'hmax.txt' u 1:2 with lp ls 1
```

or

```
set logscale x
unset logscale y
plot 'hmax.txt' u (log($1)):(log($2)) with lp ls 1
```

or take the absolute value abs() if you want to plot `log($2)` nevertheless in a logscale.

```
set logscale xy
plot 'hmax.txt' u (log($1)):(abs(log($2))) with lp ls 1
```